# Check file exists with T-SQL openrowset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using OPENROWSET operation with T-SQL MS SQL Server 2005.

How can I check if a file exists without command shell extension turned on?

Answer (score 2):

try use EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist

Comment: Also note that this is undcumented

Answer (score 1):

Use CLR stored procedure to check whether file exists.Call the procedure in TSQL and check the file existence. Check this link :
http://carlosbercero.com/post/?post=Writing_a_CLR_Stored_Procedure_on_SQL_Server

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
BEGIN TRY

    ...

    BEGIN TRY
        select
            *
        from
            OPENROWSET (...)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 7399 --have to experiment to get the right error number
           RAISERRROR (stuff about real error, 16, 1)
       ELSE
           RAISERRROR ('No file!', 16, 1)
    END CATCH

    ...

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   --normal error handling
END CATCH
```